# Identify old shower handle

Tags: shower

My shower handle got stuck so I’m not able to adjust the temperature (left one). The right handle is to adjust the volume.

I’m trying to find a replacement part online but could not find one with similar design/style.

Can anyone identify it? Or can I replace it with single handle design easily?

[image]
(click to enlarge)

Edit: Adding images after taking off the front plate
Any suggestion on finding the same part online?
[image]
[image]

Comment: Replacing it with a single handle will require breaking the wall and replacing at least two tiles, possibly more.  That's not a huge job if you have spare tiles, but it's much bigger than fixing the mixer!  Remove the two screws holding the cover plate, and look for brand/model markings.  Post more pics with the cover off.  If the bathroom has its own shutoff (in the basement maybe, or somewhere in the bathroom) you can try to disassemble the handle to see why its stuck, and maybe it accepts generic parts.

Comment: What country are you located in? It might help tracking down a manufacturer.

Comment: California faucet is the brand. Good luck